# Locking main() thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Not exactly sure on the terminology here but here I go basically I have the main() thread of my application that starts and calls two threads, one sets up an event handler to wait for specific registry keys to change, while the other starts a timer to write any changes made to an xml file every 5 mins or so and runs continuously. The issue I have is that once the two methods called are initialized it goes back to main and ends the program. My relevant code sections can be found below, so any help would be appreciated:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        runner one = new runner();
        runner two = new runner();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(one.TimerMeth));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(two.start));

        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();

        thread1.Join();
        thread2.Join();
    }

public void TimerMeth()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);

        timer.Interval = 300000;

        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        file write = new file();
        write.write(RegKeys);
    }

public void start()
        {
            if (File.Exists("C:\\test.xml"))
            {
                file load = new file();
                RegKeys = load.read(RegKeys);
            }

            string hiveid = "HKEY_USERS";
            WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            string id = identity.User.ToString();

            string key1 = id + "\\\\Software\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows NT\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\Windows Messaging Subsystem\\\\Profiles\\\\Outlook\\\\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046";
            List<string> value1 = new List<String> { "01020402", "test" };

            valuechange = new RegistryValueChange(hiveid, key1, value1);
            valuechange.RegistryValueChanged += new EventHandler<RegistryValueChangedEventArgs>(valuechange_RegistryValueChanged);

            try
            {
                valuechange.Start();

            }
            catch
            {
                StreamWriter ut;
                ut = File.AppendText("C:\\test.txt");
                ut.WriteLine("error occured in starting management");
                ut.Close();
            }

            file test = new file();
            test.checkfile("C:\\test.xml");

        }

void valuechange_RegistryValueChanged(object sender, RegistryValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
// deals with the returned values
}
```

Basically all the code works fine I've been testing it in a windows form application but now I need to run it in a standalone app with no interface in the background and need it to keep writing to the xml file and the change event to stay alive.

Comment: Have you tried adding something like `Console.ReadLine();` (to prevent exiting without intervention) within the `main` routine? I haven't tried it but will just take a couple minutes to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods will run once, then the thread will exit. There is nothing to keep them running.

Try this:

```
thread1.IsBackground = true;
thread2.IsBackground = true;

public void start()
{
 while(true)
 {
    // ... do stuff
    Thread.Sleep(1000*60*5) // sleep for 5 minutes
 }
}

public void TimerMeth()
{
    while(true)
    {
        file write = new file();
        write.write(RegKeys);

        Thread.Sleep(30000);
    }
}
```

As other posters have noted, you will also then need to ensure your main method doesn't exit. Making the application a windows service seems like a good way to solve this in your case.

You might also want to handle [ThreadInterruptedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadinterruptedexception.aspx) and [ThreadAbortException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx) on your threads.

And if you really want to get into the nitty gritty of threading, check out this [Free C# Threading E-Book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joe Albahari.

Comment: Cheers was able to stop the code falling through and ta for the little e-book it did help.

Answer (score 2):

Try building this into a [windows service](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Creating-a-Windows-Service-with-C-Sharp-introduction/).

This [thread](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=68937) contains two suggestions for finding the logged on user from a windows service, but I am not sure if they work.

Comment: Already was doing that which works fine apart from I need it to run as the logged on user (as in not local system, local service or network service as the SID returned is not the one I want). Already posted up a question on how to resolve that and they suggested I created a .exe instead of a Windows service.

Answer (score 2):

As you can expect, the `Main()` method is terminating because execution flows out of the `Join()` methods back to the main thread, and then terminates.

Either place loops in the methods `TimerMeth()` and `start()`, or more appropriately redesign the application into a Windows Service (as zac says).

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues.

Your first thread is simply creating a timer (which launches another thread). This thread is terminating very quickly, making your call to `Join` rather meaningless. What this thread should be doing is actually doing the waiting and the checking. You can easily adapt your code like this:

```
public void TimerMeth()
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);

    timer.Interval = 300000;

    timer.Enabled = true;

    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            OnElapsedTime(null, null); // you should change the signature

            Thread.Sleep(30000);
        }
    }
    catch(ThreadAbortException)
    {
        OnElapsedTime(null, null);

        throw;
    }
}
```

Obviously you *should* change the signature of `OnElapsedTime` to eliminate the parameters, since they aren't used here.

I have a feeling that something is amiss in the way that the file handling is being done, but given that I don't understand exactly what that code *does*, I'm going to refrain from commenting. What, exactly, is the purpose of the file? Where is `RegKeys` defined?

Answer (score 1):

To keep the main thread alive, one of the simplest ways is to add the following line to the end of your **main** function:

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Thread` will terminate when your `ThreadStart` function returns, which allows the main thread to continue after `Join()`.  Since you are just setting up a timer to fire off, the method will return very quickly.  You need to provide a lock of some sort to keep your application from exiting.

Also, it doesn't look like you need to use threads at all to do what you are trying.  Instead, just use the `Timer` and provide the lock to keep your `Main()` from terminating.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like all of your functions are completing? ie, they all "fall out the bottom". Once all the functions have run through there is nothing left to do and your app will close. You want to run a loop of some sort in main.

You will also need to take a look at your timer. I suspect it is currently being garbage collected. You create it in the scope of your function but that function is being left so there is no longer a reference to your timer and it will be collected. Your timer needs to be a root.